# Django In-Memory SQLite3 Database

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite, in-memory-database

I'm trying to have a purely in-memory SQLite database in Django, and I *think* I have it working, except for an annoying problem:

I need to run `syncdb` before using the database, which isn't too much of a problem. The problem is that it needs to create a superuser (in the `auth_user` table, I think) which **requires interactive input**.

For my purposes, I don't want this -- I just want to create it in memory, and I really don't care about the password because I'm the only user. :) I just want to hard-code a password somewhere, but I have no idea how to do this programmatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disconnect `django.contrib.auth.management.create_superuser` from the `post_syncdb` signal, and instead connect your own function that creates and saves a new superuser `User` with the desired password.

Answer (score 6):

Any inputs or prompts of django-admin.py may be suppressed using the **--noinput** option, such as

```
./manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

This will skip the super user creation on the initial syncdb run and thus requires you to create one either using fixtures or an custom method as receiver of the `post_syncdb` signal.

See [django-admin.py and manage.py in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---noinput%20%22django-admin.py%20and%20manage.py%22%20in%20Django%27s%20documentation):

> **--noinput**
>
> Use the --noinput option to suppress
>   all user prompting, such as "Are you
>   sure?" confirmation messages. This is
>   useful if django-admin.py is being
>   executed as an unattended, automated
>   script.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use fixtures:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm unfortunately not quite sure how to use them, though -- how would they be able to create a password for Django itself?

Comment: Once you have a running copy with the user you want simply export a fixture from the users model.  ./manage.py dumpdata auth.User > initial_data.json.  This fixture will be loaded every time you run syncdb https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures